# Having some parameters Injected with DI and some assigned manually

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject, .net-core-3.1

In a .NET Core 3.1 console application I want a Class that would have some parameters in constructor injected but some that I could assign manually. For example something like that but with IConfiguration Injected:

```
static void Main() {
    var myObj1 = new MyClass(1);
    var myObj2 = new MyClass(2);
}

public class MyClass {
    public MyClass(IConfiguraiton config, int myVal)
    {

    } 
}
```

I tried this with Ninject:

```
static void Main()
{
    kernel = new StandardKernel();
    kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    kernel.Get<MyClass>();
}

public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(IConfiguraiton config)
    {

    }
}

public class Bindings : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
       var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile($"appsettings.json").Build();

       Bind<IConfiguration>().ToMethod(ctx => SetupConfiguration()).InSingletonScope();
       Bind<MyClass>().ToSelf().InTransientScope();
    }
}
```

I managed to make simple dependency injection, but haven't had any success making injection with parameters.

I've read a lot of people suggesting that it's better to pass parameters into methods of the class rather than constructor, however in my situation this isn't an option in addition I'm a software engineering student, and would like to learn how to do this, since it might be useful in some situations.

Comment: What is the point of dependency injection if you want to create it yourself? Have those values encapsulated into another config provider etc. which is injected into the class.

Comment: Yeah this one is a bit of a non-starter. What you can do to solve it is use Property Injection (NInject supports it) and then supply your OTHER properties in the initialier like so `var my = new MyClass { myProp = 1 };`. However, property injection is commonly frowned upon as it is not obvious to the developer which things are injected and which are not, and it is easy to miss some when testing that code

Comment: Also - `however in my situation this isn't an option in addition` - why not?

Comment: What is the function of the injected value? Is this value constant, not changing while the application runs, and available at startup, or rather a runtime value that might change on each request. Or perhaps something in between. Please describe its function and origin; the correct solution is highly dependent on the answer you give.

Comment: Alright, sorry for so little information about context. So MyClass will be a class responsable for downloading files of a website. So the value that I want to pass would be a link to that website. I dont want to pass the value into method because there will be quite a few methods in this class that will use the link, and so it would be so much more sense using constructor for this right? I cant have that value in the config because I would have several instances of the class created to download files from different websites.

Comment: @Ermiya Eskandary I get what you are saying, but I want to use Dependency Injection on it so it would inject IConfiguration into the class automatically. Or am I not understanding correctly how dependency injection works ?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Sounds very much like the OP needs to create an object with stuff that a DI container would have registered, AND a context-sensitive parameter only available at runtime where construction is required. This is exactly what the Factory pattern is used for, and plays very nicely with DI concepts. In fact, Ninject supports this case directly via the Factory extension (see my answer below).

Answer (score 0):

This is a situation where the [Ninject.Extensions.Factory](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Factory/wiki) is useful, as it is made exactly for this situation. It does pull in the Factory dependency in addition to [Castle.Core, as it uses DynamicProxy](https://github.com/castleproject/Core/blob/master/docs/dynamicproxy.md) under the hood (as a SE student, playing with this library is a good idea for using the [interceptor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interceptor_pattern)).

To use it, you define a Factory interface like so:

```cs
public interface IMyClassFactory
{
    MyClass Create(int myVal);
}
```

Note that the `Create` method returns `MyClass`, and the argument(s) to the `Create` method match exactly in type and name to the arguments you wish to provide. The argument type(s) you want injected must be registered with the kernel. Unfortunately, it is easy to make a mistake here - if you specify a parameter that does not exist in the factory interface it is ignored, but if you forget one it will throw an exception when called.

Next, register `IMyClassFactory` like this: `Bind<IMyClassFactory>().ToFactory();` and remove your binding for `MyClass`. Then wherever you need to create an instance, inject `IMyClassFactory` and call `Create`: `kernel.Get<IMyClassFactory>().Create(2)`

You can achieve the same result without using [Ninject.Extensions.Factory](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Factory/wiki) by writing and registering your own implementation of `IMyClassFactory`, essentially doing the same thing that the code the Factory extension ends up emitting. A full sample is below using both methods based on commenting in/out the registration (note the output if you add `.InSingletonScope()` to the registration of `IConfiguraiton` - both approaches respect the binding scopes of Ninject).

```cs
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Bind<IConfiguraiton>().To<Configuraiton>();
        kernel.Bind<IMyClassFactory>().ToFactory();
        //kernel.Bind<IMyClassFactory>().To<NinjectMyClassFactory>().InSingletonScope();
        var factory = kernel.Get<IMyClassFactory>();
        var one = factory.Create(1);
        var two = factory.Create(2);
    }
}
public interface IMyClassFactory
{
    MyClass Create(int myVal);
}
public class NinjectMyClassFactory : IMyClassFactory
{
    public NinjectMyClassFactory(IResolutionRoot resolutionRoot)
    {
        ResolutionRoot = resolutionRoot;
    }
    private IResolutionRoot ResolutionRoot { get; }
    public MyClass Create(int myVal)
    {
        return ResolutionRoot.Get<MyClass>(new ConstructorArgument("myVal", myVal));
    }
}
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(IConfiguraiton config, int myVal)
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Created MyClass({0},{1})", config.MyNum, myVal);
    }
}
public interface IConfiguraiton { int MyNum { get; } }
public class Configuraiton : IConfiguraiton
{
    static int CreateCount;
    public Configuraiton()
    {
        MyNum = Interlocked.Increment(ref CreateCount);
    }
    public int MyNum { get; }
}
```